# What does "should likely" mean?

Tags: meaning

For example

> You should likely do something.

Does it mean "you should do something" or "you can do something"?

Comment: Basically it means, "You should probably try to do something."

Comment: I sympathise with the question.  What I suppose it means is that it is likely (though we don't know for sure) that you should do something. It wouldn't win a prize among idioms designed for clarity, that much is certain.

Comment: You *should* do something and I am expecting you to do it. Not a good way to express it.

Comment: There is no reason to close this.  It's a question about a polite imperative.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a popular locution.  The Ngram viewer finds no instances, and the google reports only about 5K hits.  It seems to mean "this is my advice about what you **should do**, and it is **likely** you'll find the advice worthwhile.  A typical example from a [cyber-discussion](http://http:/http://forums.menshealth.com/topic/wife-says-she-wants-zero-responsibility-for-my-son-her-step-son) about what parents should do when they don't agree about child-rearing issues:

> [Y]ou two have to decide how to handle those kinds of issues - and you
>   **should likely do** it away from your son.